# mod_rewrite: redirect requests from localhost to remote server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a following scenario:

- Remote server with some webapp running at `http://remote/webapp`
- Local machine inside corporate network
- Corporate proxy between them
- Apache with mod_rewrite running on my local machine

I would like to have the mod_proxy rewrite every request like `http://localhost/webapp?someparams` into `http://remote/webapp?someparams`.

Currently I have the following httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs"

<Directory />
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.+) http://remote/$1 
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Which results in mod_rewrite transforming `http://localhost/webapp?someparams` into `http://remote/C:/Apache2.2/htdocs/webapp?someparams`

How to configure mod_rewrite to handle it correctly?

Comment: I think that's called Reverse Proxying, you may want to look that up

Comment: I think Deny from all is the culprit here ,  Allow from all will work I think , can you try once and also , here your expectation is unpredictable , you are using windows absoute path in an URL , really not able to figure out what want

Comment: The fact that windows absolute path appears in the URL is due to misconfiguration of the mod_rewrite and this is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Jon for inspiration, finally mod_proxy + mod_rewrite worked:

```
# Global context
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+) http://remote/$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://remote/
```

I know that this is a simplified and coarse solution, but works for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you have access to vhost/server config, you should ditch mod_rewrite and just use mod_proxy:

```
ProxyPass /webapp http://remote/webapp
ProxyPassReverse /webapp http://remote/webapp
```

and get rid of the 2 mod_rewrite lines (which is redirecting, not proxying):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+) http://remote/$1
```

Note that if you have cookies, you may need to reverse map their domains.using [ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreversecookiedomain).

---

Also:

> The fact that windows absolute path appears in the URL is due to misconfiguration of the mod_rewrite and this is what I'm trying to avoid

This is not a misconfiguration with mod_rewrite. When you put rewrite rules inside a `<Directory>`, the filepath is used in the match instead of the URI-path. According to the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> **What is matched?**
>
> In `VirtualHost` context, The Pattern will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
>
> In `Directory` and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that lead the server to the current `RewriteRule` (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).

Comment: ProxyPass used with domain name was causing 'DNS lookup failure' error and I can't use IP instead of domain name. But thanks!